# Конструкция IF ELSE не видит локальную переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, локальные-переменные

Не могу изменить переменную внутри функции. В коде ниже, переменная **а** - локальная. Она служит счётчиком. После взаимодействия с условными операторами - она должна измениться. И функция **func()** должна вернуть обновлённое значение переменной **a**.

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def func (array): 

    a = 0 # Счётчик. Локальная переменная.

    for i in array: # Тут я проверяю каждую переменную из списка на тип
        
        if i == int: # Если переменная - целое число
            if i <= 3:
                a += 1 # Вот я хочу изменить локальную переменную, но она ни в какую
            elif i >= 3:
                a -=1
        
        elif i == str: # Если переменная - строка
            print ("It's a string!")

    return a

print (func(list_1)) # Должно получиться 2, но оно выводит 0
```

Я прочитал много статей про область видимости переменных. Но в этой ситуации я зашёл в тупик.

Comment: Условия `i == int` и `i == str` всегда ложные. Никакое число никогда не будет равно классу int, никакая строка никогда не будет равна классу str. Область видимости тут ни при чём, вы просто неправильные условия написали

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Comment: У вас неверное понимание ошибки. Если бы переменная была не видна, то была бы ошибка, что к переменной обращаются до инициализации. А этой ошибки нет, значит перменная видна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сравниваете значение с типом, а это всегда будет `False`.

Вам нужно проверять тип значения, т.е. делать так:

```
if isinstance(i, int):
  ...
if isinstance(i, str):
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно тип переменной и напрямую на равенство сравнивать:

```
if type(i) == int:
```

Или:

```
if i.__class__ == int:
```

Но проверка через `isinstance` более "каноническая", она включает и проверку на подклассы. Хотя в вашем случае это без разницы.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде работает так как нужно.

```
num = [1, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2]
def func(num):
    a = 0
    for i in num:  
        if i <= 3:
            a += 1  
        else:
            a -= 1
        print(a)
func(num)
```

Comment: Если нужно только 1 число а не весь список то опусти Print(a) на 1 Tab ниже

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]